# What happens when you call Assembly.CreateInstance more than once for the same assembly?

Tags: .net, silverlight

In an app I am working on, I use reflection to dynamically load animation assemblies (and create instances from them). However, when I am done with the animation, I dispose of the wrapper on the animation and forget about it . . . which works until I need the animation again.

Creating the animation calls `Assembly.CreateInstance(AnimationUnit.TypeName)` to dynamically create an instance from the animation assembly, since each assembly is a uniquely named dll file. Is the Silverlight Runtime smart enough to only load the assembly once, even if I make this call multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Assembly.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.createinstance.aspx) doesn't create an instance of the *assembly* - it creates an instance of a type *within* the given assembly.

Comment: I think what he meant was whether or not is the assembly the type belongs to is loaded into memory every time you call the CreateInstance method

Comment: @sternr - Exactly. I have now edited my question to reflect that idea.

Comment: @Corey: But these are *instance* methods. You've already got to *have* an `Assembly` in memory in order to call the method. Why would it load another copy of the assembly when you're calling it on an assembly?

Comment: @Jon: Thanks. It makes sense now. Also, from some test cases I just ran, the assembly is only loaded once, despite my repeated calls to get instances of my animation objects from it. Was just curious since there are TONS of these animation assemblies, with 1 assembly bet animation. Answer accepted because it led me to the correct answer.